# Visual Studio 2015 Universal Windows XAML designer surface loading forever

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, designer

[PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6BVI.png)

I start a new Universal Windows in C# project.
I would like open the MainPage.xaml but that is load to much, more then 3 hour. Can you help me. This is my first question in here by the way. :D

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to SO. If it really takes that long than I'd say it's one of two things. Either your machine (hardware) is not up to spec memory/cpu wise, or there's some really bad things being done in the code. Without more info though it's hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the similar question in the past. I used the following steps to diagnose and try to solve this issue:

1. Check the [Visual Studio 2015 System Requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2015-sysrequirements-vs) to see if your environment meet the requirements. If it doesn't meet requirement, you might need to upgrade it.
2. I saw your screenshot, the error code shows "could not find App.g.i.cs file". You could try to Clean and Rebuild(you can open your project in file explore and find "obj" folder, delete it and Clean and Rebuild your project) to see if it will work.
3. Close your Visual Studio and restart it to see if it will work.
4. Create a new blank UWP project to see if it will work.
5. Try to [repair your Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx#Repairing%20Visual%20Studio)

Comment: Thank you very much. The step 5 helped me. But after it a get another problem, but i can solved thet with this instructions [link] (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/388dd1c5-ca01-4538-baa8-7555100e4f80/visual-studio-12-designer-could-not-be-started-because-of-a-permissions-issue?forum=vseditor) _italic_ **bold** `code`